# Migrating MongoDB to DynamoDB

Tags: mongodb, migration, amazon-dynamodb

Following this thread [MongoDB to DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161684/mongodb-to-dynamodb)

I've followed the steps, and I'm receiving output that the DynamoDB cannot receive.

for example if I export it to JSON if the export file have a field in the MongoDB that represented by int the export file writes it $numberInt.
For example: if I have a field in the JSON

```
{a: 10}
```

it will compile to:

```
{a: {$numberInt: "10"}}
```

Is there something I'm missing? is there a simple solution except parsing the JSON file from $numberInt to normal int?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your case and tech stack. In my case, a compiled JS object should look like this:

```
{ a: { 'N': '10' } }
```

If you are processing your data using JS, you can use `dynamodb-auto-marshaller` to convert a JS object:

```
import { Marshaller } from '@aws/dynamodb-auto-marshaller'

const data = { a: 10 }
const converter = new Marshaller()
const result = converter.marshallItem(data)

// result = { a: { 'N': '10' } }
```

Hope this is helpful to you. ：）

Comment: That looks like that would work!
But what we did we made a recursive function that compiled the JSON to the way the Mongo understands :\

Comment: There is also `marshall` and `unmarshall` in`@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html)